# How to organize a multiprocess application in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing, process, multiprocessing

The source code is as follows:

```
const listener = new Listener ();

listener.start ();    

process.on ('SIGTERM', () => {
  listener.stop ();
});
```

I want to split `Listener` into two, in order to bring the code to a child process.

How to do this properly using Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad, but you should look into node clustering - which is the built-in framework to handle child processes : https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html